# DD-WRT - Connection count for a device is very high?

Tags: router, lan, dd-wrt, powerline-networking

My desktop PC has a connection count of 238 on the DD-WRT lan page. Other devices have only a few.

I connect to it using a powerline adapter. Could that be the reason?

What does the number mean anyway?

Answer (score 3):

That many connections is usually from browsers, monitoring programs like anti virus, or file sharing apps.

1. To understand those connections open the Task Manager (assuming windows 7 or 8) by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete on the keyboard.
2. In the task manager, click the performance tab, and click resource monitor.
3. In the resource monitor, click the TCP connections tab.

Keep in mind some apps can consume a lot of connections without actually being visible. For example, the akamai netsession is a file sharing service that lets other customers download from your computer instead of software manufacturers websites. To check and remove it, run through the following list.

1. Open the control panel
2. Search for 'uninstall a program' without quotes
3. Look for a program called something similar to akamai netsession
4. Double click to uninstall it, if you found it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to your adapter. Connections are made whenever you connect to another machine. For example loading a webpage can open dozens of connections, but they are usually closed properly. Connections can be more persistent, when using bittorrent for example

However, sometimes they're not properly closed, but they'll eventually time out. The default timeout in DD-WRT is 3600 seconds, and the default max connections is 4096. So, 238 is not many, or anything to worry about.

To see what your PC's open connections actually are (assuming Windows) use `netstat -an | find /v "127.0.0.1" | find "ESTABLISHED"`.   You can also use the `b` switch `netstat -anb` to see what process has the connection open.

Actually the default 4096 max connection count was for routers with 8MB of RAM in mind. You can't increase this with the GUI (or may not need to), but can increase it by executing a couple of commands and editing the startup script in **Administration/Commands**. [Here's more on that](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Router_Slowdown#Increasing_Max_Connection_count_beyond_limits_of_GUI).